# Percentage Calculation in Java

Tags: java, double, decimal, long-integer, percentage

I am trying to calculate percentage for work using java. Here is the sample code,

```
public class WorkCalculaor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WorkCalculaor wc  = new WorkCalculaor();
        System.out.println(wc.calculateWork(50, 40)); // should be 120%
        System.out.println(wc.calculateWork(60, 100)); // should be 33.33%
    }

    public double calculateWork(double target, double actual) {
        //work = [100 + ((Target – Actual) /Target)*100 ] %
        double work = (target - actual);
        work = work/target;
        work = work*100;
        work = 100 + work;
        return work;
    }
}
```

My actual requirement is ,i wil have actual minutes and target minutes as input and then i need to calculate below percatage on those target and actual minutes.

[100 + ((Target – Actual) /Target)*100 ] %

I mean percentage calculation.

SO, if i give calculateWork(50, 40) i should get 120% and if i give calculateWork(60, 100) i should get 33.33%.

I have written the above code and its working fine. Is this is the right approach?

Also only 2 decimals of percantage value is needed.

can anyone suggest?

Thanks.